# fopen with 'w' flag returns "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS"

Tags: c, fopen

Okay, so I'm trying to open a file `"dump.txt"` using `fopen` with the parameter `w`. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) "**"w"** Opens an empty file for writing. If the given file exists, its contents are destroyed." In which case, `fopen("dump.txt","w")` should not return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, because that would (and should) not matter with the `w` flag. I even tried the full path to `"dump.txt"`, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Comment: `fopen` doesn't *return* `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`; it returns a `FILE*` value. It may or may not set `errno` to some particular value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file already exists and is being overwritten, `fopen()` would return a non-NULL `FILE*` pointer so you can write to the file, and so you should not be doing any error handling to begin with.  Don't check for an error code unless `fopen()` returns NULL.  Even then, make sure you are getting the error code from [`errno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) and not from `GetLastError()`.

Comment: I am actually programming in assembly, and the debugger automatically retrieves the last error, hence why I mentioned it. Thanks for clearing this up for me!

Comment: `CreateFile()` (which `fopen()` calls internally) sets `GetLastError()` to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` on success if an existing file is opened when using the `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag. This is [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx).  So this situation is one of you simply misinterpreting the fact that a non-zero error code is being reported in a non-error condition, letting you know that an existing file is being overwritten.